# Не выводятся данные sql-запроса из БД. В чём может быть причина?

Tags: php, sqlite3

Вот такой вот код:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('sqlite:data.db', null, null, $options);
$stmt = $db->query('
                    SELECT a.*, c.category AS category_name
                    FROM articles AS a JOIN categories AS c
                    ON c.id=a.category
                  ');

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

// print_r($result);

?>

<?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
    <p>ID: <?= $row['id'] ?></p>
    <p>Date: <?= $row['date'] ?></p>
    <p>Category: <?= $row['category_name'] ?></p>
    <p>Title: <?= $row['title'] ?></p>
    <p>Text: <?= $row['text'] ?></p>
    <p><a href="?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>">More…</a></p>
    <br />
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Не выводит ничего. Даже ошибок и предупреждений.

Вывод `print_r($result);` — Array ( )

Выходит, что массив пустой. Где может быть ошибка?

Comment: Просмотрите данные таблиц, точно ли у вас есть данные удовлетворяющие критерию.

Comment: Да есть так-то. В первой таблице (10 строк) id(integer), title(text), date(integer), category(integer), text(text). Во второй (2 строки) — id(integer), category(text). Вообще, нужно, чтобы вместо category(integer) из первой таблицы, выводился столбец category(text) из второй таблицы, т. е., чтобы выводилось название категории, вместо её id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если запрос выполняется без ошибок, но не возвращает ни одной строки, это означает что в БД отсутствуют данные, удовлетворяющие запросу.

Comment: Но данные-то есть) Наверное запрос неверно сформулирован. Посмотрите пожалуйста, верно ли?

Comment: Stack Overflow не предназначен для того, чтобы "посмотреть на запрос". Это не бесплатный сервис по написанию и не форум. Здесь не пишут код, не заглядывают телепатически в чужие базы данных, не разглядывают  запросы, не занимаются гаданием "где бы могла бы быть ошибка?". Здесь только отвечают на конкретные вопросы. На вопрос я ответил.

Comment: Чтобы разобраться с новой проблемой, надо задать новый вопрос и привести в нем дампы обеих таблиц и запрос. Поскольку не видя данных, невозможно сказать, правильный запрос, или нет. А лучше всего будет посмотреть на данные **самостоятельно**. Поскольку проблема не в том, есть ли данные в таблицах, а в том, удовлетворяют ли они условию. Но честно говоря, такой способ разработки, когда буквально каждая строчка кода пишется путем задания кучи вопросов на Stack Overflow,  сообществом не приветствуется. Либо учите программирование, либо обратитесь на фриланс биржу, чтобы вам написали код за деньги

Comment: Понятно. Я понимаю, что нехорошо постоянно задавать подобные вопросы, но я предварительно стремлюсь читать об этом, а когда не нахожу информации, то задаю вопросы. На фриланс-биржу не вариант, мне ведь кодить ещё дальше, а если всё целиком сделают за меня, я просто не пойму как это работает и не смогу продолжить работу дальше. Вот я и думаю, что данные не удовлетворяют условию. Буду отталкиваться от этого ключа.

Comment: Старость не радость. У меня во-первых, была пуста таблица №2 (с категориями), во-вторых было неверно сформулировано условие, а в третьих была пуста голова. Стоит ли ответить на собственный вопрос?

Comment: Нет. @Ипатьев уже пояснил в чем ключевая причина. Если каждый будет задавать вопрос, ответом на который будет "у меня просто исходные данные не те", то мы здесь погрязнем в однотипных ответах.